# Unable to use ionic 3 native calendar plugin

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to use ionic calendar plugin in my project but I am getting
: `Object(...) is not a function` whenever I try to show the calendar.
**My html code is:**

```
<div class="appoint-ser"><span  (click)="opencal()">Select Appointment Date</span></div>
```

And my **ts code is:**

```
 import { Calendar } from '@ionic-native/calendar/ngx';
      constructor(

    private calendar: Calendar,
    ) {


      }

     opencal(){
        this.calendar.createCalendar('MyCalendar').then(
          (msg) => { console.log(msg); },
          (err) => { console.log(err); }
        );
      }
```

Comment: what is the ionic-native wrapper version you are using? Use v4.x with ionic 3.  This seems to be a common issue for ionic native 5.x and ionic 3

Comment: currently i have 2.9.0 ionic-native wrapper version

Comment: `import { Calendar } from '@ionic-native/calendar/ngx';` is for ionic natve 5.x. GO through https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/